# Issue with `uniq` method working with arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

When calling `uniq` on an array created by importing numbers from a text file, the method is not removing the last duplicated element in the array.

This creates an array of examples values (1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4). Each value was its on line on the text file:

```
file_data = Array.new    
file_name = File.readlines("filename.txt")
```

This shows the expected results:

```
puts file_name # => 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4
puts "#{file_data.length}" # => 8
```

Then, this shows unexpected results:

```
puts file_name.uniq #=> 1, 2, 3, 4, 4
puts "#{file_data.length}" #=> 5
```

I entered the values directly into an array rather than by importing them through a text file and did not have this problem, so it appears to be something in the file read command. I am lost on how to fix this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You've narrowed it down to the file being the issue but given us nothing about the contents of the file...

Comment: It is a .txt file with each numbered element of the array (the numbers shown above after the #) on its own line.  There is nothing else to the file right now.  It will later be expanded and not be so overly simplistic, but I kept it simple for purpose of just trying to work with .uniq and ensure that it worked.  If there is something else I could provide in terms of information, please let me know--but there isn't anything else to the file that I could think of that might be informative.

Comment: Is it possible that last line include a /r/n ? Can you try to add a carriage return ?

Comment: some possibilities: Encoding issue, whitespace, invisible chacters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably a whitespace issue.

Try:

```
file_name.map(&:strip).uniq
```